# Skin texture gets lighter at certain places (ears and nose) in Cycles

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, toon-shading

So I started following a tutorial on creating a versatile skin shader:https://youtu.be/8ae6gm3MZy4

When I use this material in my own project the ears and nose get a lighter skin tone then the rest of the mesh.

The ears are loose objects and don't change colors when joined with the base mesh. I thought it could be the specular, but sliding it around doesn't change anything. I also checked the face orientation already and it seems all to be fine.

In the material viewport everything looks the same and fine, but whenever I go into the rendered viewport the ears and nose change colors.

I also tried UV-mapping the mesh, wondering if it would be fixed. But this wasn't the answer.

[image: Material viewport Blender]
[image]

**In eevee everything seems to be fine:**
[image: Eevee viewport]

**The node set-up is as followed:**
[image: Node setup skin material]

Does anyone know where these lighter colors come from? Thanks in advance!

If you are in need of the blend file you can get it here: https://we.tl/t-d8oPiYNVIb

Answer (score 6):

You have this lighter tones in the ear and nose due to your subsurface scattering value.
You can decrease this effect by setting a lower subsurface value or lower subsurface radius value on the principled BSDF node(yellow square on picture)[image]

Comment: Thank you! never really knew what the subsurface did, gonna take a look further into it!